# iOS SwiftUI: ScrollView ignore top safe area

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios13, xcode11

I have a shared view in my app that can be called in different places.
The root of this view is a scroll view, but sometimes it ignores the top safe area and it collapses under the navigation bar.

Here two screenshots that shows better the problem:

[image]
[image]

As you can see in the second screenshot the scrollview extends for all the screen collapsing under the navigation.
How can I  avoid this?

Comment: provide trial code.

Comment: can't provide the code due to privacy, but i've fixed with .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using:

```
.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

in all the NavigationView

Comment: Does anybody have another solution?
This didn't work for me

Comment: It's not working.

Comment: This doesn't work as it only changes some unrelated property of the NavigationView style on iPad. It has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Works for me. Must be applied to the NavigationView itself, not to the content within.

Answer (score 28):

Adding `.padding(.top, 1)` to the scroll view will solve the issue.

Comment: Not a perfect solution but it does solve the issue. How would you do it so the navigation header gets pinned during scroll?

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue with the List inside NavigationView and ignored the bottom safe area.
What helped me was setting the list bottom padding to some non zero value, like this:

```
.padding(.bottom, 1)
```

It looks like a bug and this issue still exists on iOS 15.2

Answer (score 6):

[Ihor Vovk's solution works perfectly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64974289/3151675), but if you don't want a visible padding, just change it to `.padding(.top, 0.10001)`.

Comment: 0.1 doesn't work for me. 0.2 does work however, but it's noticeable. 0.15 works too, and while still noticeable it is much more discreet than 0.2. It might vary between devices though. I have only tested on one.

Comment: Any amount over 0.1 works for me... even 0.101

Answer (score 5):

Think in a simpler way, you will be surprised
please use modifier .clipped()
-> The problem is that the scroll view is allowing its content to overflow, like the masksToBounds property in UIkit, the padding(.top, 1) solution above is also a way to prevent the content from overflowing.

Answer (score 1):

You can solved it by giving padding to scroll view

```
ScrollView {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
      
        Text("test")
        Text("test")
        Text("test")
        Text("test")
        Text("test")
        
    }
}
.padding(.top, UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.safeAreaInsets.top )
```