# SwiftUI overlay respect safe Area

Tags: swiftui

I have an overlay in my SwiftUI view as follows (for simplicity purpose, I have a view with plain blue color in the code below):

```
   .overlay(alignment: .bottom, content: {
        showMenu ? Color.blue.frame(height: 150) : nil
    })
```

My problem is that it does not respect safe area in landscape mode and I see no way to customize it so that the overlay does not cross dynamic island on iPhone 14/15 pro. It is okay to target iOS 16 and above if that simplifies things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean, the overlay is not extending into the safe area?

A pre-requisite for this to be possible is that the view the overlay is being applied to must be in contact with the safe area insets. Then, just apply `.ignoresSafeArea()` *before*  applying the `.frame`:

*EDIT* If you only want it to respect the side insets, but still ignore the bottom insets, then you need to specify the `edges` for `.ignoreSafeArea()`

<s>*EDIT2*</s> deleted

*EDIT3* I managed to reproduce the issue that you were describing, where it wasn't working when the overlay contains a horizontal `ScrollView`.

To fix, `.clipped()` needs to be applied to the `ScrollView`. This prevents it from overflowing into the safe areas. This tip comes from the answer to [iOS SwiftUI: ScrollView ignore top safe area](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76347860/20386264) (you are welcome to give it an upvote).

If you only want the background color to ignore the bottom safe area insets, but not the actual content of the overlay, then `.ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)` should be moved to the background color instead.

```swift
let loremIpsum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

@State private var showMenu = true

private var menu: some View {
    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        HStack {
            Text(loremIpsum)
                .font(.title)
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: 900, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
    }
    .clipped()
    .background { Color.blue }
    .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
    .frame(height: 150)
}

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 20) {
        Text(loremIpsum)
        Text(loremIpsum)
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
    .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
        showMenu ? menu : nil
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: No. I mean I want to restrict it to safe area in landscape mode. It should not cross the dynamic island on iPhone 14/15 pro.

Comment: The answer works for the simple scenario mentioned in the question, so I accepted the answer. However for some reason, this strategy is not working for my custom view which has an `HStack` embedded in a `ScrollView`.

Comment: I meant the overlay itself has a `ScrollView`, not the main view

Comment: @DeepakSharma Answer updated again, hope the issue is cracked now.

Comment: Why maxWidth hardcoded to 900?

Comment: Ok it works even if I set maxWidth to .infinity. I think `.clipped` made a difference.

Comment: @DeepakSharma I set the width to 900 to force the text to wrap, otherwise the example would just be one long line. 900 is wider than the screen, so the `ScrollView` is still needed. Anyway, hope you have a solution now.